# convert typescript types into proto files

Tags: typescript, types, interface, grpc, proto

I am using Braintree integration for payment, I want to expose the API from my GRPC microservice. but there are a lot of interfaces that I need to create proto files for.

I am looking for a tool that can convert a given typescript types/interfaces into proto buff files.

there are few libs that can do the opposite but I searching for ones that can convert types to proto.